# Getting null value while subscribe from service to component using BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular

I am using angular 11 , I just want to get a static value from service to component.But while subscribe in component getting null value. Here is the code below

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonService} from './common.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  title = 'serviceexample';

  constructor(public service: CommonService) { }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout(()=>{       
      this.service.test().subscribe((data:any) => {
          console.log(data);
      });
    }, 3000);
   }
 }
```

### common.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CommonService {
   
  constructor() { }
  public verifydocumentMessage = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  
  ngOnInit() {
    let error = "something went wrong";
    this.verifydocumentMessage.next(error);  
  }
  public test(): Observable<any> {
   return this.verifydocumentMessage;
  }
}
```

Comment: First, the BehaviorSubject is initialized with `null`, so that is the value you will get when you subscribe. Second, `ngOnInit` will not work in a service. It is meant for components and directives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) like `ngOnInit` work with Directives and Components. They do not work with other types, like a service in your case.

You are getting null value because `verifydocumentMessage` is declared as null and your `ngOnInit` is not called.

So, simply move `ngOnInit` logic to the constructor it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Lifecycle hooks like ngOnInit in angular are applicable only for Components and Directives, not for services, so either move that logic to the constructor or write a different function and call that from your component, it should work fine then.